# Why the value of var is NAN in summation of integers

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have a method in javascript which calculates value of var sum in below code

```
 function calculateLppAmount() {
            var sum = 0;
            j$('.lppDetailAmount').each(function (i, obj) {
                sum = Number(obj.value) + sum;
            });
            document.getElementById("lppAmount").textContent = sum;
        }
```

Now when my sum is iterating and the value of obj.value is 999 then it fills the lppAmount by 999 but as soon as it exceeds 999 it gives NAN. Why is it so??

Comment: can you check the field properties that might restrict the field value when more than 999?

Comment: It works for 999 but as soon as the input is in the form 1,000 it gives NAN. Any input which has a comma in it gives an NAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
function calculateLppAmount() {
    var sum = 0;
    j$('.lppDetailAmount').each(function (i, obj) {
        sum = Number(obj.value.replace(',','')) + sum;
    });
    document.getElementById("lppAmount").textContent = sum;
}
```

Just use the `obj.value.replace(',','')` to ignore the commas.

Comment: It removed the NAN but the value of the sum is not coming out as expected it is coming out as zero. lppAmount is the span ID and lppDetail amount is the input box

Comment: See my update. Just replace the `,` with `.` -> `obj.textContent.replace(',','.')` or `obj.value.replace(',','.')` in your case.

Comment: You are on the right track the problem is with the comma when you input the value in the lppDetail input box and using your answer the value of sum is returning 0. I used console..og and the value of sum is 0

Comment: See another update. It should be `obj.value` instead of `obj.textContent` as I originally said. I didn't read that the `.lppDetailAmount` is input box :)

Comment: It worked but by replacing it with a blank space and not the dot. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Exactly, commas with empty spaces, my bad. However, be careful with this, as in some locals a comma can mark the decimal places, like -> 100,00. Which should be 100, and not 10000.